# Empty reply from server when downloading NLCD 2016 in R

Tags: r, curl, r-sf, rcurl

I am trying to download the NLCD 2016 Land Cover Dataset in RStudio. The area I am trying to get data for is roughly that of New York State. The code I am using at this point is:

```
library(FedData)
library(sf)

NYSbb <- data.frame(lat = c(40,45.2),
                 lon = c(-71,-80))
NYSbb_df <- st_as_sf(NYSbb, 
                    coords = c("lon","lat"), 
                    crs = 4326)
NLCD <- get_nlcd(template = NYSbb_df,
         label = "NYS",
         dataset = "Land_Cover",
         year = 2016,
         force.redo = T) # Left this line in here because of cancelled download attempts
```

The error I receive after running this code is the following:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Empty reply from server
```

I understand that a curl error is some sort of a server error. I am on a personal computer, and I have no problem accessing the NLCD website from my internet browser.

Comment: This might be a problem with `url`, or the `handle`. Does it work with other sources?

Comment: What do you mean by other sources?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to making a plain HTTP request to a server that does HTTPS.

Try changing your url to `https://...`

Comment: Where would I go to change the URL? I never input one, R does so automatically in the get_nlcd call.

Comment: Sorry, I answered too quickly. Are your `lat` and `long` in the right order?

Comment: According to some github threads, yes. Presumably that wouldn't matter for a curl error.